# Is $\gamma(t) = (|t|,t)$ plot $y = x$?

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric

I have this parametric curve :

$\gamma(t) = (|t|,t)$ with
$\gamma(t) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$

And I have to say if the plot is the line of equation $y = x$. Here's my answer:

> $x(t) = |t|$ and $y(t) = t$
>
> if $y = x$, $y(t) = x(t)$ on $\mathbb{R}$
>
> or $t = |t|$ if and only if $t \ge 0$

So it's false. Is my answer correct?

Comment: (+1) Nice job! Another way to go is simply to note that $x$ cannot take on negative values, and so the plot is not of *any* non-vertical line. (In fact, not of any line at all, but that's enough for these purposes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. For $t \geq 0$, $\gamma(t) = (t,t)$ is indeed the line $y = x$. But for $t < 0$, $\gamma(t) = (-t,t)$. It is the graph of $f(x) = |x|$ rotated around the origin $90$ degrees clockwise.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm making progress yay.. :p (gonna accept the answer in... 11 minutes apparently).

Comment: Adding your progress on the problem when asking the question is very important, it helps us to give advice at the right level. It's very good that you do this. Go on, you're doing great.